# A function to print a character number of times and in number of lines

Tags: c

My task was:

Write a function that takes three arguments: a character and two integers. The
character is to be printed. The first integer specifies the number of times that the
character is to be printed on a line, and the second integer specifies the number
of lines that are to be printed. Write a program that makes use of this function.

And my code is: (i know i did not add different scenarios like if the first char is number etc, but please let me know if it looks ok)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printing_char (char ch, int numberOfChars, int numberOfLines);

int main (void)
{
    char userChar;
    int lines,times;
    printf ("please enter a character, number of times in a line, and number of lines:\n");
    while ((scanf ("%c%d%d", &userChar, &times, &lines)) == 3)
    {
        printing_char (userChar, times, lines);
    }
    return 0;
}

void printing_char (char ch, int numberOfChars, int numberOfLines)
{
    int x;
    int y = 0;

    while (++y <= numberOfLines)
    {
            for (x = 0; x<numberOfChars; x++)
            {
                printf ("%c", ch);
            }
            printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("%c", ch);` have you considered `putchar(ch);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a couple of things:

- `int lines,times;` - one declaration per line, please!
- `scanf("%c%d%d", &userChar, &times, &lines)` - where does one number end and the next start?. You need to include some terminating characters, such as `,`

  ```
  printf("please enter a character, number of times in a line, and number of lines, separated by a comma:\n");
  while ((scanf("%c,%d,%d", &userChar, &times, &lines)) == 3)
  ```
- An expression such as `while (++y <= numberOfLines)` is confusing, what value does y have at each step? It'd be better to rewrite this as a `for` loop

  ```
  for ( y = 0; y < numberOfLines; y++ )
  ```

Comment: One number ends and the next starts at *whitespace* - remember that numeric conversions skip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to comments by @GlennRogers, here's a bit of pedantry:

- consider putting `main` last to avoid the need for a prototype for
  `printing_char`
- `printing_char` should be `static`.  Seems a bad name too.
- for-loops can define the loop variable in the initial loop:

  ```
  for (int x = 0; x<numberOfChars; x++)
  ```
- nested loops are generally best avoided. Your inner for-loop would be better
  as a function:

  ```
  static void print_n_times(int ch, int n)
  {
      for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
           putchar(ch);
      }
  }
  ```
- adding a blank line after the function definition is very odd. Best not
  done.
- `numberOfChars` and `numberOfLines` are verbose for my taste. I prefer
  `n_chars`, `n_lines` (or camel-case `nChars`, `nLines`). Also, as the variables
  in `main` have exactly the same meaning, it would be reasonable to call
  `lines` and `times` the same there, ie.  `n_chars` and `n_lines`
- you have unnecessary brackets around the `scanf` call

Answer (score 0):

Expensive operations here are the nested loops and the multiple calls to the `printf` function.

These hotspots can be corrected by using the `memset` and `memcpy` functions (but be careful, you can quickly misuse them).

Only **one `printf`** and **one loop**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printing_char (char ch, int length, int lines)
{
    if (length < 1 || lines < 1) return;

    int size = length+1;
    char str[size*lines+1];

    memset(str, ch, length);
    str[length] = '\n';
    str [size*lines] = '\0';

    for (int off = size*(lines-1); off > 0; off -= size) {
        memcpy(str + off, str, size); 
    } 
    printf ("%s %d", str, lines);
}

int main (void)
{
    char ch;
    int lines;
    int times;

    printf("please enter a character, number of times in a line, and number of lines, separated by a comma:\n");
    while ((scanf("%c,%d,%d", &ch, &times, &lines)) == 3) {
        printing_char (ch, times, lines);
    }
    //printing_char('*', 4, 3);
    //printing_char('^', 0, 5);
    //printing_char('.', 3, -1);

    return 0;
}
```